# What does the connector supports on the payload adapter do?

Tags: engineering, payload, analysis, vega

Good day, I am currently doing a project for university in which I have to redesign the connector support for the Payload Adapter  (PLA 1194 VG) for the Vega(picture shown).

[image]

I would like some insights into what is the purpose of the part and what are the main loads that act on it during launch? I am unable to find any document online regarding this specific component. I would greatly appreciate any help with this.

Thank you

Comment: I would hope that whoever gave you this project also gave you authoritative data to design for, such as the loads the part is supposed to handle. It makes me a little uneasy that a part of an orbital launch vehicle is going to be designed according to specs provided by random guys and gals on the internet. (Though admittedly, the software industry has been working that way for quite a while already.) ;-)

Comment: @TooTea: I'd guess it's an student exercise project, not something that will fly.

Comment: @SF. I think so as well, but it doesn't feel like a great idea to teach engineering students to just google for the missing bits if the requirements are incomplete. (I'm saying that as an engineer myself, although I graduated long before SE became a thing, so perhaps things have changed…)

Answer (score 2):

The "connector support" supports a connector.

Here's one in use on VV04, supporting a connector for the [IXV](http://www.esa.int/Enabling_Support/Space_Transportation/IXV).
[image: adaptor]
<sup>(ESA–M. Pedoussaut, 2015)</sup>

It's on the left hand side, and you should be able to make out the bundle of cables running up through it.

The connector itself shouldn't be supporting the payload, however there is a spring, constantly under tension, to hold the connectors together.

There are some details in the [Vega user guide](https://www.arianespace.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/Vega-Users-Manual_Issue-04_April-2014.pdf#page=209), although irritatingly, it doesn't seem to specify the "maximum force of the connector spring" despite referencing it when it stipulates

> The  electrical  connectors  are  mated  on  two  brackets  installed  on  the  adapter  and spacecraft side. On the spacecraft side, the umbilical connector’s brackets must be stiff enough to prevent any deformation greater than 0.5 mm under the maximum force of the connector spring.

Comment: Are the springs mentioned the separation springs? I found details regarding the separation springs in the user guide. Is there springs for both the umbilical connector's bracket and the electrical connector bracket?                                                                Thank you for your reply.

Comment: No, the separation spring are shown on page A4-13 @Kaif